# Why does Typescript infer 'never' instead of intersection type?

Tags: typescript

Given the following example:

```js
interface Data {
    name: string;
    value: number;
}

const data :Data = {
    name: 'name',
    value: 1,
}

const updateValue = (key: keyof Data, value: string | number): void => {
    data[key] = value;
};
```

[link to ts-playgound](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgCJzHZBvAUMg5EOAWwgC5kBnMKUAcwG59CA3OAGwFcKiuSARtGYBfXLgQB7EDWQATDFnLpMyALw4WBYmUoByHRD0AaLcnbdeARlNiJ02VwAOCyADVOPdcgAUAawgAT0oAwMkYNEVjc09eGjoQemQAHz5BaABKSlZJYDl1AD5NQnlFAG1QgF1vCx5RZiA)

Typescript shows the following error:

```
Type 'string | number' is not assignable to type 'string & number'.
  Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'string & number'.
    Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'number'.
```

Which is clear and understandable. However if I add a union type to the interface like so:

```js
type MultiType = 'x' | 'y';

interface Data {
    name: string;
    value: number;
    multiType: MultiType | null;
}

const data :Data = {
    name: 'name',
    value: 1,
    multiType: null,
}

const updateValue = (key: keyof Data, value: string | number): void => {
    data[key] = value;
};
```

[link to ts-playgound](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/C4TwDgpgBAsgrgG2ASwCrmgXigcgB45QA+uIOA3AFCXIB2wEATgGYCGAxtACKvCtQBvSlBFRarALYQAXFADOwRnQDmVUVABurBHBli4EgEZM1oiYhTpIs+EjQZi+hAioBfauwD2tBVAAmvPzSPHxQ2ELq4lKyOFEQOAA0wqJaOnoAjEnq5nZWerSICEnulF4+wFBwYAEMAGraumFQABQA1hAgsu0gnsxQIawJmg16Ckq0yo4FRkwAlLIansh+YQB8gskiNawA2t0Auk2pum5UQA)

I get the following error:

```
Type 'string | number' is not assignable to type 'never'.
  Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'never'.
```

Typescript accepts it if I use the intersection type `string & number & MultiType` but it also accepts `never`.

This seems inconsistent to me. Is this maybe a bug?

Comment: Which part seems inconsistent ? The fact that it accepts `never` ?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`string & number` is equivalent to `never`, and so is `string & number & (MultiType | null)`.   There are no values which are both a `string` and a `number`, so no values satisfy `string & number` or `string & number & AnythingElse`.

Right now the latter [explicitly reduces to `never`](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/18438) because it contains unions of these equivalent-to-`never` types, which is really ugly to leave like that.  Specifically, the compiler distributes intersections over unions, so

```
string & number & ('x' | 'y' | null)
```

becomes

```
(string & number & 'x') | (string & number & 'y') | (string & number & null)
```

That type isn't particularly enlightening to people, so the compiler checks that each of those union constituents is equivalent to `never` and reduces the type to

```
never | never | never
```

which is just

```
never
```

as you saw.

---

So why doesn't `string & number` by itself get immediately reduced to `never`?  Well originally the idea was that it would help people understand where the bug in their code came from, since `string is not assignable to number` is more enlightening that `string is not assignable to never`.

Unfortunately while `string & number` is *equivalent* to `never` in terms of what values are assignable to and from it, in TS3.5 and below the compiler doesn't always treat them the same, which is confusing.

Therefore it looks like, starting in TS3.6, [empty intersections like `string & number` will be reduced to `never` explicitly](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/31838).  Once TS3.6 is released, your above code will act the same in both cases, and you'll get the `string | number is not assignable to never` error.

---

Okay, hope that helps; good luck!

Comment: I may read this a few more times, but I guess I understood this :-)
Thanks. I will use 'never' as type for value.

Comment: I'm confused... why would you want to mark `value` as type `never`?  Then you won't be able to use the `updateValue()` function because there are no values of type `never` to pass in.  Yes, you can use a type assertion to do `updateValue("name", "alice" as never)`, but that's not safe; `"alice"` is not of type `never`.  Really you want to use a generic function with `keyof` and lookup types, see `setProperty()` in [this documentation](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/What's-new-in-TypeScript#keyof-and-lookup-types) for how to do a property setter.

Comment: See [this](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgCJzHZBvAUM5EOAWwgC5kBnMKUAcwG59kA3OAGwFdzDPiAjaEwLFO7MMAAqATwAOPALJiJM+cgA+vduyYBfXLjByUS8VOPIAvMgBEADxsbb0m01wIA9iGrIAJhjgKdEwrHGYiUgobCIgbABpmNi4eAEYEkWVzeQoQMXZcXTdPbzBkTll-SAA1Dm5QgB4AaWQIO0gQX0pkAGsIaQ8YNACAPgAKXukKRrjWWp5guABtRoBdAEoKFg9gXythsIJKpYmV0KTuPTdyyoga5NGbc9iZlLWGZAB6D+QPbrhpXDXDC3OYPJ7xWweDyySg2N6fb7QKAeKAGIHVUHREjPSF-Fzwr4-PGAirAu7cB4xCEpABMAGYCYioMjUSSbuSIA9RGZVDibPj3oTfv82WTMdyVMYITYoTC4YKmSzcEA) for one way to do it.  No issues with intersections or `never` in there.

Comment: Good example. Thanks. I still don't get why I need to use the generic. To be concrete, why does [this](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgCJzHZBvAUM5EOAWwgC5kBnMKUAcwG59kA3OAGwFdzDPiAjaEwLFO7MMAAqATwAOPALJiJM+cgA+vduyYBfXLjByUS8VOPIAvMgBEADxsbb0m01wIA9iGrIAJhjgKdEwrHGYiUgobCIgbABpmNi4eAEYEkWVzeQoQMXZcXTdPbzBkTll-SAA1Dm5QgAoAawhpCmbpDxg0ALjWWp5guABtds7uzABdAEoKFg9gXysAPjCCSuH2idCk7j03csqIGuT6mx3Y3pSphmQAelvkD0a4aVwDjCP+0-P42w8PWSUGzXO4PaBQDxQAzvapfaIkC5-Z4uEH3R7It4VD7HbinGK-FIAJgAzKiwVAIVDMYccRBTqIzKpETYUTc0U8XtTsXCGSpjL8bP9AcC2eTKbggA) not work?

Comment: It doesn't work because nothing stops someone from calling `updateValue("name", 12345)` and having a `string`-valued property set to a `number`. The compiler says it doesn't know that `value` will be appropriate to write to `data[key]`. Reading a property and writing a property have different implications for type safety.  If you read from `data[K1 | K2]` you can safely save it to a variable of type `data[K1] | data[K2]`.  But if you write into `data[K1 | k2]` you cannot do that from an expression of type `data[K1] | data[K2]`.  The only safe thing you can write is `data[K1] & data[K2]`.

Comment: See [this documentation](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/Breaking-Changes#fixes-to-unsound-writes-to-indexed-access-types) for more info on how and why this happens with TS3.5+.

Comment: Ah. I think I get it now. By defining the key in the generics bracket I enforce that it's *exactly* the same key for both parameters whereas in my example I just enforce that it's *any* key from Data.
Took a while to wrap my head around it, but now I get it. Thank you so much for enlightening me :-)

Answer (score 1):

Two things :

- It's only logical that TypeScript doesn't accept `string | number` as type for your `value` parameter, because all of the following :

  - `string | number` is not assignable to `string` because `number` is not assignable to `string` in case the `key` is `'name'`
  - `string | number` is not assignable to `number` because `string` is not assignable to `number` in case the `key` is `'value'` (both of there were already true in your first example)
  - `string | number` is not assignable to `MultiType | null` because both `number` and `string` are not assignable to `'x' | 'y' | null` in case the `key` is `'multiType'`

For some reason however, in your first example TypeScript simply stops on the first "wrong" case and gives you this error (Even though there are really two things wrong already).

In the second case, you could have seen the same error message because the incompatibility of types is still there, it seems like the inference goes a little deeper and tells you that the problem is deeper than this. As to why is the error message formatted like this, I don't really know and I guess it would require going deeper into how are things inferred by the compiler here. In the end, the compiler is right, but the error message could be clearer.

---

For your second question, [the `never` type](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/What%27s-new-in-TypeScript#the-never-type) documentation says :

> The `never` type is a subtype of, and assignable to, every type

So that's why you can specify your `value` to be of type `never`, and assign it to your `data`. Because it will *never* happen.