# Is there any way to make two null values distinguishable in TypeScript at type level?

Tags: typescript, null, nominal-typing

TypeScript string types can be made unique by adding an extra field with a unique symbol to the type. However, this does not seem to work for null values. See the following example code. Is there any way to make two null values distinguishable at the type level?

```
// Works with strings

type FooString = string & { readonly _Foo: unique symbol }
type BarString = string & { readonly _Bar: unique symbol }

const fooS: FooString = 'foo' as FooString
// @ts-expect-error FooString is not assignable to BarString
const barS: BarString = fooS


// Does not work with null

type FooNull = null & { readonly _Foo: unique symbol }
type BarNull = null & { readonly _Bar: unique symbol }

const fooN: FooNull = null as FooNull
// @ts-expect-error FooNull is not assignable to BarNull
const barN: BarNull = fooN

export {}
```

I often work with existing code bases that use null values in various error situations. I am exploring the possibility of adding nominal types to null values as a first step towards more appropriate error handling. The main benefit of using nominally typed null values is that it would let me introduce appropriate type signatures without forcing me to immediately change the runtime implementation.

Comment: It seems that `null & <anything>` is `never`. Which is why `FooNull` and `BarNull` are equivalent. I don't know how you'd distinguish them, apparently [empty intersections are reduced to `never`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57198077/why-does-typescript-infer-never-instead-of-intersection-type). I suspect you might need a new value that signifies "no result" that's not `null` in order to be distinguishable.

Comment: Could you provide an example where you use the types and compare them?

Comment: It could be as simple as having `enum MyValue { EMPTY }`, so if a function could return some string or no result, you'd have `string | MyValue.EMPTY`. You can also use branding on that to customize it, so you'd have `string | (MyValue.EMPTY & { _type: "FOO"} )` and `string | (MyValue.EMPTY & { _type: "BAR"} )` as the possible results of two different functions. Then the empty values will not overlap.

Comment: @VLAZ sorry that I was not specific enough. I was referring to the example in the question, because I couldn't recreate the problem cyberixae was describing

Comment: @Bongo I added more background information to the question

Comment: @Bongo [See here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/PTAEHcHsCcGsGcBQAXAngBwKagGKUgMrLQCWAdgOagC8o8x5VAZKAN6jSYCGAJpGQBtUoAPp5IALlABXMiQCO07PFQBbAEaQBoAL4oM2AEJdoRUpRp0GFlu069+Q0cehTZCpXTWbtexCFA+THhQMkhkCBhYfSxcfAA5aQFtWjIk7VsObj5BYTF8NzlFZW8tXVAQcUTkyzJMADdMaBijE2qU0PTQTPscpxEXQo8SjTKdCuAXdtqGpsREHkwAYwETbAFMCK4pcTNGAG4F5dXOUA2I9SkXPcpDxC5LdX2JpugYecWVtbPN0CWdhLpQ6fE7rX48K5tIGIJaWHjPEAAeQA0kA) - hover over `FooNull` for example and you'd see it is `never`

Comment: @Bongo I misunderstood your question. I modified the example to a form that you can copy paste into a TypeScript module and immediately see the error. Note however that the new example code uses `@ts-expect-error` that requires TypeScript 3.9 or newer.