# Deep merging (not intersecting) two objects/interfaces makes the result unsatisfiable for contraint

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I'm trying to deep merge two objects/interfaces which inherits from the same `Base` interface, and use the result in a generic parameter which is constrained by `Base`.

```js
// pls dont judge
type UglyDeepMerge<T, U> = {
  [K in (keyof T | keyof U)]:
  K extends keyof U ?
  K extends keyof T ?
  T[K] extends Record<string, unknown> ?
  U[K] extends Record<string, unknown> ?
  UglyDeepMerge<T[K], U[K]> :
  U[K] :
  U[K] :
  U[K] :
  K extends keyof T ?
  T[K] :
  never
}

interface Base {
  name: string;
}
type DoSomething<T extends Base> = T;

// Type 'DeepMerge<T, U>' does not satisfy the constraint 'Base'.
type Test<T extends Base, U extends Base> = DoSomething<DeepMerge<T, U>>;
```

[playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/PTAEAcBsGdQEwPYDsAuoBWBXOBzApgFAoCe4eoAqjpMQCJ57gCyeATvgDwAqANJQHygAvKADeBUKADaAaVABLJKAAUAazzEEAM1BdQAH1DrNOigEoAugC4JoOXgAeKPEjixj2yqAD8t+05c3Iw1PPV9JLlkLUEdnV1gAJTwAYwRWOA5oFFZFHD5MJFUkBAB3JEFwyiiYgPjQJNT0zOzc-MLisorbKhp6RhZ2PG4ovgoowRtJMZloyaqZ0Dnp2b8auKCPHTDbSIW5pDwANzYCAF8iUnIe4gHOXgFhMVtZBSU1EK2DYJNKSzn-dbuD5eSoAwJAn7bKbVJYw1axcHfUI+HZwyQHY6sM4EHGKZysLQAQ2S5AAQoToORxOjCQBbPBWUBZHJIHAAbmxJDIoFoCAAygh6SgABa5bhrRHkymCERcDkEECgEXyWA4eTHWCEpRsVhpGxc8hcPBZcUIupSvCjCXmil4GU8-mCvDK1kca59ZhsO6jfj8C7c5xZR5Gk0WvgWv2KyQAPV8CrAACNMGhldA+KxnZhWEhYAADbKYPC5-WXXTGlAAJlNtSCYa8Ztrtvt7oYnsG3B91sblJ8StYhcWoCJMDwHINSvLFeDk44dYj8ckoFjOMVWrgStFsBKaVU0BL3JDKAAzNXAaA6xQu7AI49eQKhaLXddbkN7hRff7yIHj9PQ7bw02C4xt4QA)

I'm not sure to understand why this is happening.

Why do I get this error since `DeepMerge<T, U> extends Base ? true : false` return `true`? And how can I fix it?

---

Just to avoid an XY problem, my initial issue was the following (hens why i'm deep merging, not intersecting):

```js
interface Base {
  name: string;
}
type DoSomething<T extends Base> = T;
type Test<T extends Base, U extends Base> = DoSomething<T & U>;
type test = Test<Base & { age: string; }, Base & { age: number; }>["age"]
//   ^? never
// i need this to be `number`, not `never`
// see: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57201439
```

[playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgEJwM4oN4ChnIhwC2EAXMhmFKAOYDcuAvrmAJ4AOKAIgPYDKvUmAAWdADwAVZBAAekEABMMaTBAB8yALzJJjdl10QqUmfIhKV6LABpkAVTMLlqrJp19BwsSFqmAZA7q+pwokFTaRibWKIHYyHC05JTUdPTITHYxyHEJSRQgAK7EAEbQ6UzqANoARIkQNQC6uAD0LQTIAHoA-EA)

Comment: stupid but working solution is to add `& Base` where needed

Comment: @Dimava Indeed! It could do the trick. But it doesn't explain why just the DeepMerge doesn't work

Comment: Given how complicated `UglyDeepMerge` is, are you saying you expect the compiler to understand that `UglyDeepMerge<T, U>` is assignable to `U` for *arbitrary* `U`?  The compiler can't perform abstract reasoning on generic conditional types, and the deep nesting doesn't help either.  You fix it by fixing `UglyDeepMerge` to be less crazy, or by wrapping its definition in `Extract<..., U>` to tell the compiler it will be assignable.  Both are shown [here](https://tsplay.dev/WJV0gW).  Does that fully address your question? If so I'll write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: Your solution seems to fit my use case, thanks!
`UglyDeepMerge` is just a deep merge generic i wrote without much thought. I did try a few other implementations i found online just to check if the issue was coming from my `UglyDeepMerge` impl, but i always ran in the same error (which i still don't understand).

Comment: "I still don't understand" Let me try again: in general the compiler can't verify that `Y extends Z` implies `ComplicatedThing<Y> extends Z` when `Y` is generic. *You* only know that `UglyDeepMerge<T, U>` extends `Base` when `U extends Base` because you wrote it  yourself to do that. Someone else looking at that... thing... might well be unable to verify it, and the compiler doesn't have the benefit of human-level intelligence and abstract reasoning. We can't expect it to notice arbitrary higher-order properties of generic types. Does that make sense now or am I still missing something?

Comment: Ok i think i get it. The addition of `Extract` affects the generic in the same way as the condition i showed with `DeepMerge<T, U> extends Base ? true : false`. Thanks for the explanation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've written `UglyDeepMerge<T, U>` with the intent that the result will be assignable to `U` no matter what `U` is.  So if `U` is a [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) type [constrained](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html#generic-constraints) to `Base`, then `UglyDeepMerge<T, U>` will also be constrained to `Base`.  Unfortunately the compiler does not know this; the implementation of `UglyDeepMerge<T, U>` is a fairly complicated [conditional type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html), and the compiler do much type analysis on generic conditional types.  Such types are often *opaque* to the compiler, which *defers* their evaluation.  When you plug in specific types for `T` and `U`, the compiler will be able to see that the result is constrained to `Base`, but it does not make the logical leap from such specific individual cases to the abstract generic case.  Such reasoning is beyond the abilities of the compiler, presumably until such time as it achieves sentience (not currently included in the [TypeScript Roadmap](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/Roadmap#future)).

If you want the compiler to understand that `UglyDeepMerge<T, U>` is assignable to `U` for all `U`, you'll have to refactor in some way.  One possibility is to simply wrap your current definition in `Extract<⋯, U>` as follows:

```
type UglyDeepMerge<T, U> = Extract<{
  [K in (keyof T | keyof U)]:
  K extends keyof U ? K extends keyof T ? 
  T[K] extends Record<string, unknown> ? U[K] extends Record<string, unknown> ?
  UglyDeepMerge<T[K], U[K]> :
  U[K] : U[K] : U[K] :
  K extends keyof T ? T[K] : never
}, U>

type Test<T extends Base, U extends Base> = 
  DoSomething<UglyDeepMerge<T, U>>; // okay
```

That's because [the `Extract<T, U>` utility type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#extracttype-union) is a conditional type of the form

```
type Extract<T, U> = T extends U ? T : never
```

and the form is simple enough that the compiler can see that the result will always be assignable to both `T` and `U` (the true side of the conditional results in `T` which is re-constrained to `U`, so is assignable to `T & U`, while the false side results in `never`, which is also assignable to `T & U`, so no matter what, `Extract<T, U>` is seen as assignable to `T & U`).

Another possibility is to try to simplify your definition to something where the assignability is so direct that the compiler can see it, such as possibly:

```
type DeepMerge<T, U> = (
  T extends object ? {
    [K in keyof T]: K extends keyof U ? DeepMerge<T[K], U[K]> : T[K]
  } : unknown
) & U;

type Test<T extends Base, U extends Base> = 
  DoSomething<DeepMerge<T, U>>;
```

which works because it's an [intersection](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#intersection-types) of something and `U`.  This might or might not be the form you actually want to use, since the output types will involve nested intersections... but it has the advantage of being more direct.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=17&ssc=71&pln=16&pc=1#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgEJwM4oN4ChnIhwC2EAXMhmFKAOYDcuAvrmAJ4AOKAIgPYDKvUmAAWdADwAVZBAAekEABMMaTBAB8yALzJJjXLiKkMHRCgDqvKAGsVeAuy7IAqrQA2bbhAgcAstFoIKQAaF00dAFF5KEQwcXsCZABtAGlkUGQACmsINl4YXWQAH2QcvILnAEoAXTJ8RLS5BWVS3PyXZAB+ZEb5CCUVMvbpTvqCSVTqmT6B5AAlCAQrRXEqGhBaUIBXEGsQXgB3EE1u50np5pUFpagVtbpt3f2jk7GXd09vPwCgiZTq0Jnf6aOqJFznChAqaQiFvXqXVrlQrdP7QwgQABu0HqTEB6gMDk4KEkECoUgu-Ra6CwgIps2pGm0yD4gmEYg24lcHi8Pn8UECITC6kYLAMjh4Xz5AskeKZmXq0ialJUvAARgArRZgLrIBIEVLpECI4a1Hp0lpDCo6nnffm-SaAyYg3STHHICg7PaHEC4SrIABkLn04t0pLiipmVLUtKV9LU4WZAiEEFEEhtUt+eOFuCAA)